# Japanese full width digit issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

On Japanese windows OS there are half width and full width character modes.

I have property page in MFC with text box which accepts only integers. Also I have override OnKillActive() method which in turn calls CPropertyPage's OnKillActive method.

When user enters full width integers and clicks Apply button then my class's OnKillActive() method gets called which then calls OnKillActive() method of CPropertyPage. But CPropertyPage::OnKillActive() gives me error "Please enter an integer".

Same code works with half width characters.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: The property page itself doesn't know anything about integers, it's the input control which complains to its parent (the property page). But you haven't stated which control you use for Japanese number input.

Comment: I am using CEdit control with ES_NUMBER flag.And I am getting the error message from CPropertyPage::OnKillActive method.